# PHP SoapServer return empty xml document (empty string)

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

`handle()` from `SoapServer` return empty xml document (empty string). My code is basically:

```
    $soapService = new soapService();

    $soapServer = new \SoapServer('/path-to/my.wsdl');
    $soapServer->setObject($soapService);
    $soapServer->handle();
```

No errors are thrown... what i'm doing wrong?

The wsdl is [here](https://github.com/italia/fatturapa-php-sdk/blob/master/SDICOOP/server/RicezioneFatture_v1.0.wsdl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my self... i have tried the soap only with HTTP GET request and SoapServer send response only with HTTP POST.